# Number of solutions of an equation with upper bound

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics

Is there an elegant formula for number of integer solutions of the equation
$$
x_{1}+x_{2}+\dots+x_{n}=K,
$$
where $0\leq x_{i}\leq k_{i}$ for all $i$? The number depends on $K$, $k_{i},i=1,2,\dots,n$ and $n$.

Comment: Are the solutions taken from any particular set, say, integers/rationals/real numbers?

Comment: $x_{i}$ must be integers of course.

Comment: There is no "of course". Please add the information to the post.

Answer (score 0):

If a solution to this problem existed it, would be way too elegant.
Sorry for providing a wrong solution earlier, I made a blunder in my calculations.
Coming to the derivation for the most general case, given $a_i <= x_i <= b_i$, solve for:
$$\sum_{i = 1}^nx_i = K$$
We can approach this problem via multinomial theorem. We find the coefficient of $x^K$ in the following expansion:
$$(x^{a_1} + x^{a_1 + 1} + ... + x^{b_1}).(x^{a_2} + x^{a_2 + 1} + ... + x^{b_2}).(x^{a_3} + x^{a_3 + 1} + ... + x^{b_3})......(x^{a_n} + x^{a_n + 1} + ... + x^{b_n}) \hspace{1cm} \forall 0 \leq x < 1$$
This is same as finding the coefficient of $x^{(K - {\sum_{i = 0}^n{a_i}})}$ in:
$$(1 - x)^{-n}.(1 - x^{b_1 - a_1 + 1}).(1 - x^{b_2 - a_2 + 1}).(1 - x^{b_3 - a_3 + 1})......(1 - x^{b_n - a_n + 1})$$

> If $b_i \to \infty $ the problem becomes the easily solvable one where $x_i$ has no upper bound, giving us: 
>   $$(1 - x)^{-n}.(1 - 0).(1 - 0)....(1 - 0) = (1 - x)^{-n}$$
>   Here the coefficient of $x^{(K - {\sum_{i = 0}^n{a_i}})}$ is $^{n + l - 1}C_{n - 1}$, where $l = K - {\sum_{i = 0}^n{a_i}}$.

However for the general case, although the formula is derivable, still it would be one very large formula, one which would not be worth remembering, thanks to the randomness in the values of $a_i$ and $b_i$.

Comment: Can you check your work? It's not quite clear to me what you are aiming for. In general, I believe that a PIE approach has to be used, and I'm slightly surprised if it simplifies to just a binomial coefficient.

Comment: @CalvinLin I will take 24hrs to elaborate, today is my Linear Algebra exam. Meanwhile, give me a counter example where you think my solution would fail. I derived it using multinomial theorem.

Comment: E.g. let $n=10, k_i = 1, k = 5$. We are looking for 10 0-1 integers that sum to 5, so clearly there are $ { 10 \choose 5 } = 252 $ ways. Following your logic, I get $b = 10 \times 10 - 5 = 95$, and ${b+n - 1 \choose n-1 } = {104 \choose 9}$. In the event that you had a typo, there is no ${ k \choose 9 } = 252$.

Comment: Also, if $k_i > K$, then increasing it will not affect the number of possibilities, but it likely will affect your constant $b$, and hence your solution. Of course, we could limit $k_i \leq K$ as a workaround.

Comment: @CalvinLin You are right I made a blunder when I considered $X_i=k_i-x_i$, as this method will start giving us results less than $k_i$ including negative results. I will delete my answer in 2 days if I am unable to comeup with something good.

Comment: @CalvinLin I changed my answer to something meaningful.

Comment: Right, that's the "best" way that I know about. It is "equivalent" to PIE.